# Connecting to IBM DB2 Database through OLE DB?

Tags: managed-metadata, data

Is there a way to have a Data Source connection to a IBM DB2 database through OLE DB? I have tried all different kinds of variations of the connection strings from

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/add-a-database-as-a-data-source-HA010355745.aspx

I have also seen this [IBM DB2 database connect to Sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66043/ibm-db2-database-connect-to-sharepoint) which did not help and it requires a third party connector.

I am frustrated because the connection and tables work just fine in MSAccess I would assume if I can connect in Access Sharepoint would allow the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement and ended up creating a linked server in Sql Server, linked to the DB2, and a "bridge" DB in Sql Server that gets data from the linked server, by exposing it through a view. Then in SP Designer, I created a data source (or BCS external content type) connected to the DB in Sql Server.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes that helps thank you, after digging around some more I kind of figured I would have to go that route. Not unless I want to buy a third-party business connector.

Comment: I am having trouble creating the view for the linked server I know I have the rights. But it is not letting me queue the linked server.

Comment: I got the view to work and I can see it in SharePoint but no data.